# Encrypt folder Windows 7 home

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I have Windows 7 HOME OS
I used Truecrypt for encryption of my whole drive. But this solution has now 2 disadvantages for me,

1. development of Truecrypt is probably stopped and software is marked as unsafe
2. password protection in bootloader does not allow me to use wake on LAN and connect to PC using VNC remotely

Do you know about any alternative software for data encryption? My requirements are

1. I want to have encrypted few folders or whole disk
2. computer can boot windows without password and I will need to enter some password later after start of windows

I want to have encrypted folders or whole disc on the machine, that can be started remotely and I want to connect to this machine using VNC.

Do you have some ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TrueCrypt you can do exactly what you are looking for. It is not limited to whole disk encryption, try this:

1. Open up TrueCrypt
2. Click on "Create Volume"
3. Click on "Create an encrypted file container"
4. Select either standard or hidden, check the descriptions there to find what suits you better.
5. Select the place where you want the **file container** to be created. **Note, that it will create a file container, do not select a file to encrypt, select a new file to be created.

Then follow common sense and explanations in TrueCrypt software.

50GB container should be enough.

Then after finishing all the steps in the set-up wizard, press on "Select file" and find the container you created. Then press on "Mount" and enter the password. Now you should have your virtual encrypted drive loaded. Open up "My Computer" and open up that new drive. Now you can put files/folders there and they will be encrypted.