# Encryption Software for a running system

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption

I'm using Windows 7 Profesionell. So I sadly don't have access to Bitlocker.

Truecrypt sugests to use Bitlocker, but since this is not an alternative for me (I can't/won't buy Ultimate) I would like to ask if there are any other Encryption Tools to secure a running system. I wan't to be able to encrypt a whole drive without removing my files/programes there. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Just try a [search on truecrypt](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=truecrypt+answers%3A1) here at our site, and answers are popping up: [Alternatives to TrueCrypt?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt) / [Encrypt folder Windows 7 home](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/encrypt-folder-windows-7-home) / [What could replace TrueCrypt?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10455/what-could-replace-truecrypt). Have you checked them? Do they fit?

Comment: Why not TrueCrypt itself?